# How to disable touch in fragment area

Tags: android, android-fragments, touch, esri

I am developing an app that have map and fragment. Map Contents is fragment in front of map. When i touch in map contens fragment map affected from my touch and zoom in, zoom out etc. All i want to do is disable touch event on map contents fragment but i dont want to lose my click events in map contents fragment. Only disable fragment area for map content.

I have framelayout and added it when click actionbar menu items.

Thanks in helpings.

Here my code;

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            if (fragmentmapcontent.isVisible()) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentmapcontent);


            } else {


                if (fragmentmapcontent.isAdded()) {

                } else {
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapcontents, fragmentmapcontent, "Map Content");

                }


                fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentmapcontent);

            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you tried setTouchModeAbove method??

Comment: I didn't try. How can i try can you explain briefly ?

Comment: BaseActivity.sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);

Comment: Thanks for commet will it affect my fragment click event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve this issue.

When make fragment clickable:true, everything works okey.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the ontouchListener() of the fragment, and inside its onTouch() overridden method, return false and consume the event.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But i think if i implement ontouchListener of the fragment, will my fragment affect ? For example i have button in fragment when i implement ontouch listener my button will be clickable or not ?

Comment: No the button will not be clickable in this case :)